# Django use UTC offsets for current timezone

Tags: django, timezone

Django attempts to address the timezone problem by storing dates internally in UTC and converting them to the client's timezone for display. This sounds fine and good in theory, until you realize two major things:

- Many timezones can and do exist inside of the same UTC offset.
- Since there are no timezone HTTP headers, we need to determine the timezone of the client manually, and this requires the use of JavaScript. However, JavaScript can only reliably determine the UTC offset of the client and may not guess the correct timezone.

With these two problems in mind, I assume a simple solution would be to ignore timezones, DST, etc. altogether and rely instead on the client's current UTC offset. On each page load, JavaScript on the client would update the client's cookie with the client's current UTC offset and middleware in Django would load that value for each request.

Here is the problem: Django makes use of `get_current_timezone()` which retrieves it's data from the value set when `timezone.activate()` was last called. `timezone.activate()` takes a timezone object as an argument.

Is there a way to use `timezone.activate()` with only a UTC offset?

Comment: "However, JavaScript can only reliably determine the UTC offset of the client and may not guess the correct timezone." Well, it can only determine the UTC offset of the client *at an arbitrary point in time*. That can usually be used to detect the right time zone even when there are multiple time zones that have the same UTC offset right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution you describe, of getting the client's current UTC offset and sending back to the server, either via a cookie, or some other mechanism, is a common approach.  Unfortunately it's flawed.  Just because people do this doesn't make it a good idea.

The problem is that the offset you gather from the client is for a specific moment in time.  However, you may not be working with that same moment in time on the server.

For example, you might call `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()` on the client, which gives you a value of `480`, which is 480 minutes West of UTC, or `UTC-08:00` (note the sign inversion).  So you pass 480 to the server, load a date from the DB in UTC, and apply the offset.  Except, perhaps the date you loaded was from several months ago, and the client's offset for *that* date was `UTC-07:00`.  You have therefore applied the wrong offset, and produced a resulting value that is an hour off from what it should be.

A time zone cannot be identified by an offset alone.  A time zone identifier looks like `"America/Los_Angeles"`, not just `UTC-8`.  This is a very common mistake.  Read more under "time zone != offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

There are only two correct ways to handle this scenario:

1. Use a library like [jsTimeZoneDetect](https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect) or [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) to *guess* the time zone of the browser, then let the user pick their time zone, defaulting to the guessed value.  You can then use the selected or guessed time zone in your server-side code with Django or whatever.
2. Send only UTC to the client, do the conversion from UTC to local time in the browser using JavaScript.  (The browser understands the *behavior* of the local time zone where it is running, even if it has trouble *identifying* it.)  The catch here is - older browsers might possible convert older dates incorrectly, due to [this bug](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/06/07/javascript-date-type-is-horribly-broken/).  But for the most part, this is still a reasonable approach.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to see. Ultimately whether or not I let the user choose their timezone as opposed to depending on a guess from moment-timezone depends on balancing user friendliness and user needs with the importance of these dates in the system. I don't think that accuracy in the dates will be so important that I can't depend on an educated guess.

Comment: FYI - tz guessing was just added in the last version, so do file issues if you have them.  The API is `moment.tz.guess()`.